# parsing command-line arguments with boost.program_options - C++

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to parse command line arguments with boost. Here's my code (I am only including the part I need help with):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>

using std::cerr;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
namespace po = boost::program_options;

try {

    po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
    desc.add_options()
        ("help", "produce help message")
        ("compression", po::value<double>(), "set compression level");

    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(po::parse_command_line(ac, av, desc), vm);
    po::notify(vm);

    if (vm.count("help")) {
        cout << desc << "\n";
        return 0;
      }

    if (vm.count("compression")) {
        cout << "Compression level was set to "
             << vm["compression"].as<double>() << ".\n";
      } else {
            cout << "Compression level was not set.\n";
            }
      }
    catch(exception& e) {
        cerr << "error: " << e.what() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
    catch(...) {
        cerr << "Exception of unknown type!\n";
    }
```

I have my main function set to:

```
main(int argc, char const *argv[])
```

but, the code I was following https://github.com/boostorg/program_options/blob/develop/example/first.cpp contained these parameters:

```
int main(int ac, char* av[])
```

When I comile it, it spits out this and I am completely lost:

[Terminal return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWN7m.png)

Comment: Either just change your main function to "int main(int ac, char* av[])" or find every occurrence of "ac" and change it to "argc" and likewise "av" to "argv" and you should be good to go

Comment: As for the names of the arguments, they don't really matter. `argc` and `argv` are just two old common names, as are the abbreviations `ac` and `av`. You could name them `foo` and `bar` if you want to.

Comment: True but he cut and pasted the code from the example which uses those specific arguments throughout the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You also forgot to include exception - here is your code working..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <exception>

using std::cerr;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::exception;
namespace po = boost::program_options;

int main(int ac, char** av){

try {

    po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
    desc.add_options()
        ("help", "produce help message")
        ("compression", po::value<double>(), "set compression level");

    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(po::parse_command_line(ac, av, desc), vm);
    po::notify(vm);

    if (vm.count("help")) {
        cout << desc << "\n";
        return 0;
      }

    if (vm.count("compression")) {
        cout << "Compression level was set to "
             << vm["compression"].as<double>() << ".\n";
      } else {
            cout << "Compression level was not set.\n";
            }
      }
    catch(exception& e) {
        cerr << "error: " << e.what() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
    catch(...) {
        cerr << "Exception of unknown type!\n";
    return 1;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Compile this with

```
g++ -std=c++11 cmd.cpp -l boost_program_options
```

And you should be fine

Actually you can leave out "std=c++11" if you want to. I have tried it with both and its ok