# How can I clean up this C++ snippet for command line arguments?

Tags: c++, linux, c++-cli, command-line-arguments, helper

I'm trying to develop a scoring engine in C++ for vuln remediation practice development, but it's been a few years since I last touched C++, would you guys mind helping me clean up this bunch of if, else if statements, or should I just leave it as it is. All suggestions are welcome.

I tried a switch case statement because I'd been working a lot with python and bash the past few years, but I remembered that C++ only supports integers for case statements, I was wondering if perhaps I should use mappings and incorporate switch cases or if that'd make the code less readable.

```
#include <iostream>


struct commandLineArgs {
    const char* filePath = "./tmp.yaml";
    bool silenceOutput = false;
    std::string runType = "";

    void parseArgs (int argc, char *argv[]){
        if (argc > 1){
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++){
            std::string argumentValue = std::string(argv[i]);

            if (argumentValue == "--debug" || argumentValue == "-d"){
                
            }
            else if ((argumentValue == "--path" || argumentValue == "-p") && i+1 < argc){
                filePath = argv[i+1];
            }
            else if (argumentValue == "--help" || argumentValue == "-h"){
                
            }
            else if (argumentValue == "--quiet" || argumentValue == "-q"){
                silenceOutput = true;
            }
            else if (argumentValue == "check" || argumentValue == "s"){
                runType = "check";
            }
            else if (argumentValue == "score" || argumentValue == "c"){
                runType = "score";
            }
            else if (argumentValue == "readme" || argumentValue == "rd"){
                runType = "readme";
            }
            else if (argumentValue == "encrypt" || argumentValue == "e"){
                runType = "encrypt";
            }
            else if (argumentValue == "prompt" || argumentValue == "p"){
                runType = "prompt";
            }
            else if (argumentValue == "info" || argumentValue == "i"){
                runType = "info";
            }
            else if (argumentValue == "version" || argumentValue == "v"){
                runType = "version";
            }
            else if (argumentValue == "release" || argumentValue == "r"){
                runType = "release";
            }
        }
    }
    }
} cmdArgs;
```

Comment: *All suggestions are welcome* -- You could use [boost program options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466939/parsing-command-line-arguments-with-boost-program-options-c).  Information [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/program_options.html).

Comment: Is C++/CLI relevant here? Or just the spamming in tags?

Comment: You can use [getopt](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) on Linux.

Comment: Minor point: `if (argc > 1) for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)` doesn’t need the `if` part.